# Map 5xx ApiGateway Errors to Another service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Hi I want to map APIGateway errors (5xx) to another service like SQS or Lambda.
Is this possible? I'am unable to find any docs to figure this out.

Comment: can you define what you mean by "map" the errors to another service?

Comment: i mean when a 5xx error is produced I want to push the request body/headers to some other service

Answer (score 2):

Probably not exactly what you want but you can setup an alarm in CloudWatch based on number of 5xx errors and send it to SNS. You can subscribe your SQS to that SNS topic then.

Comment: Yeah I can do that. But I don't want to lose the request. That is why I want to configure  on the API gateway itself.

Comment: Do you mean HTTP request parameters and body?

Comment: Yes exactly. Is there a way?